# Get a part of an C# dataset and c opy it into another dataset

Tags: c#, .net, dataset

I have a dataset with one datatable. Now I want to set a filter on this table and copy the result to a dataset of the same type, so that I have a new dataset with only the result of the filtering. How can I do this?

Does the following code work?

```
ds.Tables[<table name>].DefaultView.RowFilter = "ProductId=5";
newDS = ds.copy();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
DataSet filterResult = new DataSet();
filterResult.Merge(inputDataset.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Where(r => r["Property1"].ToString().Equals("SomeFilter") || r["Property2"].ToString().Equals("Some other filter")).ToArray());
```

Please note that DataTable offers Select method, but it throws some very weird exceptions from time to time, hence I prefer working with enumerable list of rows and lambdas instead.